# How do I scroll with "overflow: hidden;" on body while keeping the side menu hidden?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have "overflow: hidden;" on body to keep the slide menu hidden from scroll / view.

I want to keep it as it is but with vertical scroll enabled:

http://jsfiddle.net/stritar/RWmW5/

```
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="primary_menu" href="#">LINK</a></li>
                <li><a class="secondary_menu" href="#">Link small</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="main-content">
            <div class="swipe-area"></div>
            <div id="sidebar-toggle">
                <svg data-toggle=".container" class="inline-svg" width="42px" height="42px" viewBox="0 0 42 42" enable-background="new 0 0 32 22.5" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"      xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
                <!-- Generator: Sketch 3.0.4 (8054) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
                <title>Group</title>
                <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
                <defs></defs>

                <g class="svg-menu-toggle" sketch:type="MSLayerGroup">
                <circle class="round" fill="#3B3B41" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" cx="21" cy="21" r="21"></circle>
                <rect class="bar" fill="#F2F2F2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="12" y="26" width="18" height="4"></rect>
                <rect class="bar" fill="#F2F2F2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="12" y="19" width="18" height="4"></rect>
                <rect class="bar" fill="#F2F2F2" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" x="12" y="12" width="18" height="4"></rect>
                </g>

                </svg>  
            </div>

            <div class="intro">

            </div>
            <section class="test">
                test
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Consider hiding the menu differently to ensure it is always hidden when you want it to be. Use `display: none` to remove the container completely and then `display: block` to display again when toggled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `overflow-x: hidden`:

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
font-family: helvetica;
font-weight: 100;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

And jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stritar/RWmW5/

Answer (score 0):

Try: `overflow-x: hidden;` on `body, html`

Answer (score 0):

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-weight: 100;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: You have to enable vertical scroll right?? If so put 
overflow-x: scroll

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to your answer to improve it.